# Directive default scope value is not set?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to set default value in my directive like this but its going to be null

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  }])
  .directive('myDialog', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        name: '=?'
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
      link: function (scope, element) {

      },
      controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.name = 'Tobias';
      }
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gVLvFwdXp0oxmJUOAMMN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ui9EqKNeUc3K01L1el0d?p=preview

Because when you call the directive, you do not pass in the binding property.

Bind the `name` to the directive:

```
<my-dialog name="name">Check out the contents, {{name}}!</my-dialog>
```

Since you are using `transclude: true`. Angular will create a separate scope for the (`transclude scope`) transcluded content, i.e., `Check out the contents, {{name}}!`. This scope is prototypically inherits from the parent scope, and it is a sibling of the `isolated scope`. So here `{{name}}` is not accessing the name on the isolate scope. Instead, it is accessing `transclude scope` (and traverse upstream to its parent scope, where you do not set the `name`).

Use `<my-dialog name="name">...` will create a `name` property in the parent scope and `two-way` bind to the directive. In this way, changing the value inside the directive will also change the value outside.

Comment: Any Idea why this text doesn't hide ?
http://plnkr.co/edit/2l2W8Bxv4hHuHeJ4ziEI?p=preview

Comment: [You should use `ng-hide="istrue"`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide): http://plnkr.co/edit/CLWcdXUeIMPU2FbtFhVE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

## Colliding Scopes

You are having an issue because you have a transcluded scope and an isolate scope colliding. Remove `scope: { name: '=' }` to interpolate the `name` on the controller scope. Unless you need to keep the scope from inheriting from or colliding with the parent scope, an isolate scope isn't typically needed.

If you need to keep the directive's scope isolated then don't remove the above and add the name attribute to the element and set it to the scope property you want to use: `name="name"` for example.

Given the following:

```
scope: {
  name: '='
}
```

This means you are two-way binding to the scope property defined in the `name` **attribute** on the element and calling it *name* on the **isolate scope**. If you said `somename: '=thatName'` then you would two-bind to the `that-name` attribute but call it "somename" on the isolate scope.

In two-way binding, changes on the directive scope **will** affect the parent scope. If you want to one-way bind (changes won't affect the parent) you can use `name: '@'` and if you want to bind to the value of the name attribute you can use `name: '&'`.